# Remove blue highlight from text

Tags: css

I'm using custom CSS buttons. Whenever I hover around it, it gets a blue highlight under the text inside the button (more like a blue underline).  can't seem to figure it out, despite all my efforts, it seems to be futile.

Here's my code:

```css
.btn {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  appearance: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 2px solid #e74c3c;
  border-radius: 0.6em;
  color: #e74c3c;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
  align-self: center;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1;
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 1.2em 2.8em;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.btn:hover,
.btn:focus {
  color: #fff;
  outline: none !important;
}

.second {
  border-radius: 3em;
  border-color: #ec6800;
  color: #FFF;
  background: #ec6800;
  background-position: 0 0;
  background-size: 200%;
  transition: background 150ms ease-in-out, color 150ms ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-custom">
  <div class="container">

    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <a href="signup.php"><button class="btn second">SIGN UP</button></a>
    </ul>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <a href="signup.php"><button class="btn sixth">LOG IN</button></a>
    </ul>

  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
a{
  text-decoration: none !important;
}
.nav a{
  text-decoration: none !important;
}
.btn {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  appearance: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 2px solid #e74c3c;
  border-radius: 0.6em;
  color: #e74c3c;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
  align-self: center;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1;
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 1.2em 2.8em;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.btn:hover,
.btn:focus {
  color: #fff;
  outline: none !important;
}

.second {
  border-radius: 3em;
  border-color: #ec6800;
  color: #FFF;
  background: #ec6800;
  background-position: 0 0;
  background-size: 200%;
  transition: background 150ms ease-in-out, color 150ms ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-custom">
  <div class="container">

    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <a href="signup.php"><button class="btn second">SIGN UP</button></a>
    </ul>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <a href="signup.php"><button class="btn sixth">LOG IN</button></a>
    </ul>

  </div>
</nav>
```

Try to add this in your CSS code.

```
.nav a{
  text-decoration: none !important;
}
```

Comment: @Josh It's my pleasure :)

Answer (score 1):

Try box-shadow: none; some browsers add this properly for underline

Something like:

```
a:hover {
    box-shadow: none;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: Let me know if it solves and also mark your question as resolved.

Comment: Thank you for reaching out too. mate